# Google Apps Admin Settings API Reseller Service Account Example

Tags: python-2.7, google-reseller-api, google-admin-settings-api

I am working on building a Reseller platform where Customers can buy Google app for Business and avail Gmail Services, I need to verify if user has setup MX records so that I can setup MX record verification automatically. So my questions are:

1. My assumption is, I can use Admin settings Api as a Reseller service account for this purpose, Is it correct?
2. What is the correct scope for calling this Api, Is this https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/ ?
3. Can I get working example to accomplish this, for example for domain verification I use Python Syntax.

   service = build("siteVerification", 'v1', http=http)

   followed by

   response=service.webResource().insert(body=request_verify_domain,verificationMethod="DNS_TXT").execute()

I am looking for a similar example to verify MX records as a Reseller service account holder.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

See an end-to-end codelab from Google in several different languages:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/codelab/intro

To Answer your questions:

- You can validate sites on behalf of your customer domains using a service account on your reseller domain.
- The scope for the site verification api is: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification
- It is not possible to validate the MX records via the API.  If the site/domain itself is validated, then you'll be fine.  Mail will continue to flow (assuming you actually set up the mx records) even if the MX records are not "validated" on the domain.  Basically, validating the mx does nothing more than get rid of the little nag message in the cpanel -- it's purely cosmetic. :)